# Drag and drop items in combobox

Tags: c++, uwp, c++-cx

How can I drag and drop items in combobox to change their order? (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.combobox?view=winrt-19041)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I drag and drop items in combobox to change their order?

I'm afraid you can't implement this feature, because [`Combobox`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.combobox?view=winrt-19041) use [`ItemsPresenter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemspresenter?view=winrt-19041) to display items, but `ItemsPresenter` does not contains reorder feature. If you want to change items order,  there only way is that change the data source's order.